# URL path redirect to home but fetch path infos in PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have urls like this: https://mypage.com/username-2023

I need to exectute an index.php in the root directory and fetch the path info "username-2023" in this index.php.

I tried this:

```html
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

but i always get:

"The requested URL /username-2023 was not found on this server."

When i tried to redirect every path to "/" via .htaccess:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,R=301]
```

The parse URL PATH information is empty.

Is there any way to get this managed?

Comment: Do you need to use the parse_url() function? Why not use $_GET to grab the needed information?

Comment: With $_GET i have the same problem.